# Free Wiki and Bug Tracker for JBoss/Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, wiki

Id like to set up some easy in use and installment bug tracker and wiki(Im only interested in free solutions), what do you recommend?

P.S. I like mantis, but its written in PHP, so I cant deployed it on normal JBoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue tracker

I would suggest running MantisBT on Tomcat using [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/)

> Quercus is Caucho Technology's 100% Java implementation of PHP 5 released under the Open Source GPL license. Quercus comes with many PHP modules and extensions like PDF, PDO, MySQL, and JSON. Quercus allows for tight integration of Java services with PHP scripts, so using PHP with JMS or Grails is a quick and painless endeavor.

Even more, it support MantisBT out of the box:

> The growing list of PHP software certified running on Quercus includes DokuWiki, Drupal, Gallery2, Joomla, Mambo, **Mantis**, MediaWiki, Phorum, phpBB, phpMyAdmin, PHP-Nuke, Wordpress and XOOPS.

Regarding installation, [Tomcat instructions are available](http://wiki.caucho.com/Quercus%3a_Tomcat). Quercus is implemented primarily as a servlet and it will run in any application server including Tomcat.

### Wiki

I have had good experience with [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.org/):

> XWiki Enterprise is a professional wiki with enterprise features such as Blog, strong rights management, LDAP authentication, PDF export, full skining and more. It also includes an advanced Form and scripting engine making it a development environment for data-based applications. It has powerful extensibility features such as scripting in pages, plugins and a highly modular architecture. See the full feature list for more.

Answer (score 1):

The best ones out there are JIRA and Confluence. Not free but pretty cheap and far superior to any others i tried so far.

Both java based and run on tomcat. They also provide it for free for open source projects.

Comment: I know they are great, but I prefer more universal solutions(learn once, use anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

The Liferay Portal has a fair Wiki Portlet built-in as well.

But I agree with jbx, JIRA and Confluence are not that expensive and really worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

A nice and simple wiki is [JSPWiki](http://www.jspwiki.org/),
as issue tracker you could have a look at [JTrac](http://www.jtrac.info/).

I use both in projects, they are free and simple to setup.

Answer (score 0):

look at jboss portal - it has wiki portlet.

anyway pure java wikis and trackers are not popular, even if you find one it will have less features compared to php ones.

I suggest to create apache instance and install something like mediawiki and bugzilla (we did so).

by the way, you can run php in jboss: http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/

Comment: I think that for JBoss Portal you need more custom version of JBoss, can I run it on normal JBoss?