# How do you install Mantis (php) into Quercus (java based php engine) running on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mantis, quercus

This question explains that Quercus can be used to install Mantis Bug Tracker ( a php based application) within a tomcat installation. 
[Free Wiki and Bug Tracker for JBoss/Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545231/free-wiki-and-bug-tracker-for-jboss-tomcat)

I've now deployed Quercus successfully on Tomcat7, but I do not understand how I deploy Mantis onto Quercus, where do I actually put the files ?

Background:
I liked the idea of this because currently everything on my server is java-based, and deployed within a single tomcat installation, and I dont want to complicate my deployment environment. I looked at the pure java solution JIRA but it is very heavyweight and requires its own tomcat instance so then I have the complication of multiple ports, I then looked at the open source jtrac but wasn't impressed by its functionality.

**Update:**
I had a rethink, I installed the JIRA product with the defaults except for changing the default port to 8081 and control port to 6 and now it is working side by side with my other tomcat installation no problem :)

Been playing with JIRA as an administrator for a few hours now, and finding it a very slick and easy to use so happy man. Still an answer to the original question maybe useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to install Mantis in Quercus

### Download and preconfigure MantisBT

Download the most recent MantisBT version from the 1.2.x stream and extract it.

### Download and prepare Quercus

Go to [The quercus home page](http://quercus.caucho.com/) and download the most recent war version. You will also need to make the JDBC driver for your database available to the quercus application. The simplest way to achieve that is to copy the jar file containing the driver into `WEB-INF/lib`.

### Copy and configure Mantis

Copy all the files from the Mantis directory into the directory where you have installed Quercus. Create a file named `config_inc.php` and place your basic MantisBT configuration there. This needs to be done since typically servlet containers do not allow files deployed with the application to be overwritten. A basic example can be seen below

```
<?php
$g_hostname = 'localhost';
$g_db_type = 'mysql';
$g_database_name = 'mantis';
$g_db_username = 'mantis';
$g_db_password = 'mantis';
```

### Repackage the war file

```
jar cf mantisbt.war .
```

### Deploy the war file

This step is specific for your servlet container. For my scenario I used Tomcat and simply copied the war file into `${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps` and started the server. Afterwards I navigated to `http://localhost:8080/mantisbt/` and started using Mantis.

Comment: Thanks, think I get it now, it was where to put the mantis file in relation to quercus that I didn't understand, I was looking for some kind of install option in quercus itself

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Let me know if you have any issues with the instructions, I want to add it to the official MantisBT documentation.